# Join Two Dataframes while keeping the same format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I have two Dataframes:
df1 with columns: first_name, last_name, id, location, phone_number.
df2 with columns: last_name, id, location, employer.

I am trying to create a new dataset that displays only the columns in df1 that returns only the rows where the last_name, and id is present in df2. So I decided that a inner join on the two tables. The issue is that join appends the columns from df2 to the end of df1 so my resulting df is much larger than I need. I only care about the columns in df1.

My join was: `df1.join(df2, df1.col("last_name").equalTo(df2.col("last_name").and(df1.col("id").equalTo(df2.col("id")), "inner");`

The problem with this is I got a new table of: first_name, last_name, id, location, phone_number, employer. Where id and last_name was ambiguous.

Is there any way to keep the same table format of df1 after the join? (Without dropping individual columns, because I am using with a large table with about 30 columns).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the `join` method of a Dataframe with the following function signature (from the [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5B_%5D,usingColumns:Seq%5BString%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)):

```
def join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame
```

This will only keep 1 column of the joining columns, removing your ambiguity problem.

After that, you can just select the columns of `df1` dynamically, by using `df1.columns`. In total, it would look something like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("joe", "shmoe", 1, "x", 123),
  ("jack", "johnson", 2, "y", 456)
  ).toDF("first_name", "last_name", "id", "location", "phone_number")

df1.show
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|first_name|last_name| id|location|phone_number|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|       joe|    shmoe|  1|       x|         123|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|      jack|  johnson|  2|       y|         456|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+

val df2 = Seq(
  ("shmoe", 1, "x", "someCoolGuy"),
  ("otherName", 3, "z", "employer2")
  ).toDF("last_name", "id", "location", "employer")

df2.show
+---------+---+--------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|last_name| id|location|   employer|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+---------+---+--------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|    shmoe|  1|       x|someCoolGuy|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|otherName|  3|       z|  employer2|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+---------+---+--------+-----------+

val output = df1
  .join(df2.select("last_name", "id"), Seq("last_name", "id")) // only selecting interesting columns of df2 for the join
  .select(df1.columns.head, df1.columns.tail: _*)

output.show
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|first_name|last_name| id|location|phone_number|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|       joe|    shmoe|  1|       x|         123|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+---------+---+--------+------------+
```

Hope this helps!